# Удаление записей по условию "все кроме"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется таблица из столбцов id title createdate. Как удалить все элементы таблицы, кроме тех, которые выводятся по условию:

```
select title, max(createdate)
from table
group by title
```

| id | title | createdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Объект1 | 2022-05-01 08:00 |
| 2 | Объект1 | 2022-05-01 09:10 |
| 3 | Объект1 | 2022-05-01 21:20 |
| 4 | Объект2 | 2022-04-01 06:00 |
| 5 | Объект2 | 2022-05-01 06:00 |

в результате должна остаться 3  и  5  строка

Из вариантов как это сделать, думаю через with получить таблицу из двух этих элементов, 3 и 5 строки, с помощи outer join соединить и все удалить в результате

Comment: Все записи созданы последовательно? Т.е. с каждым новым id, createddate всегда больше предыдущей записи для каждого title?

Comment: да, всегда, но лучше конечно было бы универсальный способ узнать, под разные ситуации

Comment: не самый оптимальный вариант: `delete from table t where (t.title, t.createdate) not in (select title, max(createdate) from table group by title)`

Comment: Спасибо! Хороший вариант